# Text selection style going to the edge of a webpage

Tags: html, css, background-color, textselection

I've been looking around but there doesn't seem to much help on this.

Basically I've adjusted my text selection to a different colour, easy done. However, I was wondering how to code the selection to select to the edge of the page rather than just the text on it's own.

I've attached a screenshot of a working example to show you what I mean.

[image]

**thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest css style:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: the default colour then fills over to the edge :c

Comment: please add a code example / jsfiddle what exactly you have tried so far... thanks (and maybe inline-block is better for you than block?)

Comment: thanks @Mark & Lorenz, got it :) I am new, so still learning on how to reply in a correct way :)